# PowerShell .NET filter DataTable on complex column type

Tags: .net, powershell, datatable, rowfilter

For a reporting script I keep track of logfiles in a System.Data.DataTable with one of the columns also being of type System.Data.DataTable. This column is filled based on some unrelated code, but it can result in empty datatables in that column. I need to filter all rows which have an empty datatable in that field.

Looking at DataView Rowfilter syntax I can't figure out if it is possible at all, or how to perform the query. If I try to loop over the Rows collection of the outer DataTable and check for the nested DataTable.Rows.Count property I am stuck with the issue of modifying the outer datatable which breaks enumeration.

Example:

```
$somedt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
[void]$somedt.Columns.add('foo')
[void]$somedt.Columns.Add('bar')
[void]$somedt.Rows.Add('boo', 'bah')
#$somedt

$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
[void]$dt.Columns.Add('Title')
$dtcol = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn
$dtcol.DataType = [System.Data.DataTable]
$dtcol.DefaultValue = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
[void]$dt.Columns.Add($dtcol)
[void]$dt.Rows.Add("Orange")
[void]$dt.Rows.Add("Red")
[void]$dt.Rows.Add('Blue', $somedt)

$dt | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Which gives:

```
Title  Column1
-----  -------
Orange {}
Red    {}
Blue   {System.Data.DataRow}
```

Ideally I would do something along these lines:

```
$dt.Select("Title = 'Red'") | % { $_.Delete() }
```

But the filter should be on Column1.Rows.Count = 0 which I can't figure out how (or if possible at all).

This also does not work:

```
foreach ($row in $dt.Rows) {
    if ($row.Column1.Rows.Count -eq 0) {
        $row.Delete()
     }
}
```

as it tries changing the collection during enumeration. As stated in the error message:

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.
At line:22 char:10
+ foreach ($row in $dt.Rows) {
+          ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException


Title Column1
----- -------
Red   {}
Blue  {System.Data.DataRow}
```

And the 'Red' row is not deleted. Trying a loop on the index is also unsuccessful, as the index is also changed on every deletion.

Do I need to revert to creating an empty new datatable and add rows accordingly? Somewhat like this:

```
$filtereddt = $dt.Clone()

foreach ($row in $dt) {
    if ($row.Column1.Rows.Count -gt 0) {
        $filtereddt.ImportRow($row)
    }
}

$filtereddt | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

which correctly shows:

```
Title Column1
----- -------
Blue  {System.Data.DataRow}
```

This works, as expected, but it just feels I am overlooking something, either some advanced RowFilter syntax or some more elegant (?) way to filter a datatable. Any suggestions?

---

UPDATE

So I'm trying the suggestion from the comments to add a column which would keep track of the Rows.Count property of the DataTable object in Column1. The problem I'm running into is that to make this practical it would have to be an automatically calculated value using a DataColumn.Expression. This seems to have a similar limitation as the Rowfilter syntax, as it seems impossible to access the properties of a complex datatype.

I would like to do something like:

```
$rccol = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn
$rccol.ColumnName = "RowCount"
$rccol.Expression = "([Column1]).Rows.Count"
```

But that is not allowed.

So for now I am doing this:

```
foreach ($row in $dt.Rows) {
    $row.RowCount = $row.Column1.Rows.Count
}
```

So I can filter without creating the additional "filtered datatable":

```
$dt.Select("RowCount = 0") | % { $_.Delete() }
```

I'm still wondering if this is the most idiomatic / best solution for my script, but I'll run with it for now.

Comment: It seems like you could create a CmdLet that takes a row from the pipeline and drops it if it does not meet your filter. Your final command would then be something like $dt.Rows | Find-MySelectedRows | Format-Table

Comment: That would work, however, I need to keep the outer datatable around for some more processing. I will try to test the GC behaviour of the powershell pipeline. I haven't tested at scale but I expect the outer table to become quite sizeable (up to 50k records with a non trivial amount of data in there). So I would like to avoid keeping extra copies around in memory.
Perhaps it would be easiest to keep an extra column with the inner datatable rowcount so I can simply filter in place against an [int]..

Comment: Is there any way you could do passthru processing on the entire data set then put the filter at the end? That is; do all the work you need to do with the entire data set and still have it in the pipeline to filter at the end of the process?

Comment: Alternatively; can you add a key to the data rows, so you can build a list of keys that match the filter (a relatively small amount of data compared with the entire row set).